# Do RCDs work for DC systems?

Tags: current, circuit-protection, rcd

I'm designing a product powered by an alternator with a DC regulator that will provide me with 24 V DC and something like 100 A rated consumption. Do RCDs protects against earth leakage current in DC circuits or only in AC systems?

If not, how should I protect my system agains current leakage?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard RCDs only detect AC, as they are based around a transformer.  The live and neutral both pass through a sense coil.  Provided that the currents in each are equal and opposite, their magnetic fields cancel out, and the sense coil detects nothing.  If current leaks from the live to the earth, then the live current is greater than the neutral, and there's an imbalance in the magnetic fields.  The sense coil produces a signal, and the RCD trips.

What are you actually trying to protect against here?  24V DC is unlikely to electrocute anybody.

Comment: Well, 24 VDC is indeed a low voltage, however my worst worry is when the product is wet (it will actuate on agriculture fields), some cable brake, touches the chassi and the person touchs it. So I was thinking it is better for the product to have some protection against current leak since I do not know what faultage current will flow under the human body under this wet conditions

Comment: @NicolasCavalieri Assuming a very wet, very low skin resistance of 500 ohms (hand to foot) and measuring the current across the body would be I = V/R, so I = 24/500 = 48 mA. So its safe enough even under bad conditions.

Comment: On second thought, DC ground fault protection devices are available. So use them, 30 mA is enough to cause heart fibrillation, no point in risking lives to save money.

Comment: I wonder how acessible are these DC ground fault protection devices...

Comment: Schneider has them, so it should be fairly easy to get one: https://www.schneider-electric.com/en/product-range/1014-vigirex/